# how to iterate through nested object which is inside an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to iterate through **imageUrl** and  keep each element inside li tag. I'm fetching only one  element based on some condition, in the array then I want to iterate through all the images
**my array**

```
const productsArr = [
    {
      id: "p1",
      title: "Colors",
      price: 100,
      imageUrl: {
        imageUrl1:
          "img/Album%201.png",
        imageUrl2:
          "img/Album%202.png",
        imageUrl3:
          "img/Album%203.png",
        imageUrl4:
          "img/Album%204.png",
    },
    },

    {
      id: "p2",
      title: "Black and white Colors",
      price: 50,
      imageUrl: {
        imageUrl4:
          "img/Album%205.png",
        imageUrl1:
          "img/Album%206.png",
        imageUrl2:
          "img/Album%207.png",
        imageUrl3:
          "img/Album%208.png",
      },
    },]
```

code to iterate through the array. I think I should not use map here but I could not come up with the solution.

```
console.log(product);
 const productImage= product[0].imageUrl.map(element => {
   return <li>{<img src={element} alt={product[0].title}/>}</li>
 });
```

Comment: `Object.values(product[0].imageUrl).map()`

Comment: Could you please explain how it works?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Answer (score 0):

just iterate through array using array methods and call the nested objects using dot natation

for example :

```
productsArr.map(x =>{
  x.imageUrl.imageUrl1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the `productsArr` and then use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to create an array of values from `imageUrl` object and iterate it through it to render `li` with image.

```
productsArr.map((item)=>{
  return Object.values(item.imageUrl).map((imgUrl)=> <li><img src={imgUrl} alt={item.title}/></li>)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **:**

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.productsArr = [
      {
        id: "p1",
        title: "Colors",
        price: 100,
        imageUrl: {
          imageUrl1:
          "img/Album%201.png",
          imageUrl2:
          "img/Album%202.png",
          imageUrl3:
          "img/Album%203.png",
          imageUrl4:
          "img/Album%204.png",
        }
      },
      {
        id: "p2",
        title: "Black and white Colors",
        price: 50,
        imageUrl: {
          imageUrl4:
          "img/Album%205.png",
          imageUrl1:
          "img/Album%206.png",
          imageUrl2:
          "img/Album%207.png",
          imageUrl3:
          "img/Album%208.png",
        }
      }]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          {this.productsArr.map((obj) => {
            return Object.keys(obj.imageUrl).map((item) => (
              <li>{ obj.imageUrl[item] }</li>
            ));
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 20px;
}
li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const product = this.productsArr.map((item) => {
  return Object.entries(item.imageUrl).map((key) => {
    return {
      imgUrl : key[1]
    };
  });
});
 console.log(product[0]);
// this will give array of imgURL of product[0]
```

try this out

Comment: check https://jsfiddle.net/g2na8yq1/14/  if that works